# Как immutable объекты позволяют соблюдать принцип подстановки Лисков?

Tags: java, ооп, solid

На эти размышления меня натолкнула следующая [статья](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/09/liskov-substitution-principle.html).

В ней приведен классический для принципа Лисков пример с прямоугольник и квадратом. В коде это можно выразить так:

```
class Rectangle {

private int width;
private int height;

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public int area() {
    return width * height;
}

}

class Square extends Rectangle{

@Override
public void setWidth(int width){
    super.setWidth(width);
    super.setHeight(width);
}

@Override
public void setHeight(int height){
    super.setHeight(height);
    super.setWidth(height);
}

}

public class Use {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle sq = new Square();
    LSPTest(sq);
}

public static void LSPTest(Rectangle rec) {
    rec.setWidth(5);
    rec.setHeight(4);

    if (rec.area() == 20) {
        // делать что то полезное
    }
}

}
```

Если в метод LSPTest подставить объект Square вместо Recatangle поведение программы изменится. Это противоречит принципу Лисков.

Автор вышеупомянутой статьи делает такое заявление:

> Квадрат перестает быть нормальным прямоугольником, ТОЛЬКО если квадрат и прямоугольник являются изменяемыми! Так, если мы сделаем их неизменяемыми (immutable), то проблема с контрактами, принципом подстановки и нарушением поведения клиентского кода при замене прямоугольников квадратами пропадет. Если клиент не может изменить ширину и высоту, то его поведение будет одинаковым как для квадратов, так и для прямоугольников!

Я не понимаю почему. Может это от того что я не хорошо понимаю сам LSP или immutable. Я переписал пример:

Добавил конструктор в Rectangle:

```
public Rectangle(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}
```

И изменил методы установки длины и ширины.

```
public Rectangle setWidth(int width) {
    return new Rectangle(width, this.height);
}

public Rectangle setHeight(int height) {
    return new Rectangle(this.width, height);
}
```

Вот как изменился класс Square:

```
public Square() {

}

public Square(int width, int height) {
    super(width, height);
}

@Override
public Rectangle setWidth(int width) {
    return new Rectangle(width, width);
}

@Override
public Rectangle setHeight(int height) {
    return new Rectangle(height, height);
}

}
```

И клиентский код:

```
public class Use {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rectangle sq = new Square(4, 4);
    LSPTest(sq);
}

public static void LSPTest(Rectangle rec) {
    rec = rec.setHeight(5);

    if (rec.area() == 20) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
}

}
```

Все те же проблемы остались. Какая разница, изменяется ли сам объект или возвращается новый объект? Программа то ведет себя по-разному для базового класса и его подкласса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Призвали бы в пост, ответил бы раньше:)

Можно рассматривать разные варианты неизменяемости. С одной стороны, объект может быть неизменяемым, но при этом предоставлять методы `withNewValue` или `setValue`, которые вернут новый экземпляр объекта. А с другой стороны, тип может не предоставлять даже этих возможностей.

В первом случае объект неизменяемый, но мы можем огрести проблемы с LSP, как и проблемы с многопоточностью (это, на самом же деле, в некоторой мере один из мифов, что неизменыемые объекты безопасны в многопоточной среде; они менее опасны, но наличие методов `setXXX` может привести к гонкам). В случае "полной неизменяемости" (да, такого термина нет), этих проблем не будет.

Еще раз приведу приведенную в вопросе цитату:

> Квадрат перестает быть нормальным прямоугольником, ТОЛЬКО если квадрат
>   и прямоугольник являются изменяемыми! Так, если мы сделаем их
>   неизменяемыми (immutable), то проблема с контрактами, принципом
>   подстановки и нарушением поведения клиентского кода при замене
>   прямоугольников квадратами пропадет. **Если клиент не может изменить
>   ширину и высоту, то его поведение будет одинаковым как для квадратов,
>   так и для прямоугольников!**

Я зря сделал акцент на неизменямость. Главная мысль выделена мною сейчас жирным: даже при наличии `setWidth` методов, возвращающие новый экземпляр, нарушение LSP возможно, вы правы. Если же у клиента этой возможности нет совсем (просто такого API не существует), то тогда нарушение невовзможно.

З.Ы. Приведенный пример уважаемого @VladD будет нарушать LSP;), поскольку трюк с final противоречит следующему неформальному, но вполне вменяемому контракту: вызов метод `withXXX` не меняет тип объекта:

```
public class Use {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle sq = new Square(3);
        LSPTest(sq);
    }

    public static void LSPTest(Rectangle rec) {            
        Rectangle oldRec = rec;
        rec = rec.withWidth(4).withHeight(5);

        // Первое из следующих утрвеждений будет нарушено!
        assert(oldRec.getClass().equals(rec.getClass()), "Неявный контракт: метод withWidth/withHeight не должны поменять тип объекта");
        assert(rec.getWith() == 4);
        assert(rec.getHeight() == 5);

        if (rec.area() == 20) {
            // делать что то полезное
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь стало понятно)

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите, в чём проблема.

Пусть у нас есть ссылка на прямоугольник, которяа пришла из другой части программы. И мы надеемся, что если вы установим его ширину в 3, а длину в 4, то у нас таки-будет прямоугольник шириной в 3 и длиной в 4. Но если нам кто-то подсунул вместо прямоугольника квадрат (они совместимы по присваиванию, так что мы ничего и не заподозрим!), то у нас получится прямоугольник длиной и шириной в 4. Проблема, правда?

Теперь, в случае иммутабельности у нас не возникает этой проблемы. Что бы у нас в начале ни было — прямоугольник или квадрат — когда мы просим установить ширину в 3 и длину в 4, мы получаем *новый* прямоугольник (а не квадрат) нужных размеров. Всё работает как нужно.

Код, который вы привели в качестве примера для immutable-квадрата, неправильный. Вам вовсе не нужно для этого случая переопределять `setWidth` и `setHeight`, унаследованные функции делают уже в точности то, что надо. Ведь если поменять квадрату только длину, но не ширину, полученная фигура будет прямоугольником. Вы можете, если хотите, добавить для квадрата метод

```
public Square setSideLength(int width) {
    return new Square(width, width);
}
```

---

Фокус в том, что с мутабельными объектами вы *не можете* правильным образом переопределить методы типа `setWidth` для квадрата. А вот для иммутабельного случая можете.

---

Итак, правильный код для иммутабельного случая такой:

Прямоугольник:

```
class Rectangle {

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public final int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    // setWidth переименовали в withWidth
    public final Rectangle withWidth(int width) {
        return new Rectangle(width, this.height);
    }

    public final int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    // setHeight переименовали в withHeight
    public final Rectangle withHeight(int height) {
        return new Rectangle(this.width, height);
    }

    public final int area() {
        return width * height;
    }

}
```

Класс квадрата:

```
class Square extends Rectangle {

    public Square(int sideLength) {
        super(sideLength, sideLength);
    }

    public final Square withSideLength(int sideLength) {
        return new Square(sideLength);
    }

}
```

Теперь использование:

```
public class Use {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rectangle sq = new Square(3);
        LSPTest(sq);
    }

    public static void LSPTest(Rectangle rec) {
        rec = rec.withWidth(4).withHeight(5);

        if (rec.area() == 20) {
            // делать что то полезное
        }
    }

}
```

Этот тест работает без проблем.

Comment: не понимаю( Ведь если мы не будем переопределять сеттеры, то и в мутабельном случае все будет нормально. Вы пишите что для иммутабельного случая мы можем переопределить сеттеры, так что бы все было нормально. Но как?

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Если мы не будем переопределять сеттер, то `Square::setWidth` произведёт квадрат с шириной не равной высоте, что неправильно.

Comment: так и в immutable тоже самое будет. Если конечно задать метод setSideLength(int width) в Square то все будет хорошо. Но его можно задать и для мутабельной версии.

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: Не совсем понял, в каком случае «то же самое»? Приведите пример.

Comment: если у нас immutable версия Square и мы напишем setWidth(5). А setWidth() не переопределена. Вызовется функция из Rectangle. Которая установит только ширину, но не длину. Что не правильно для Square (ширина будет не равна высоте)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров: immutable-версия выдаст другой Rectangle. Он не обязан быть квадратом же!

Comment: @VladD а еще убедительнее можете? :) Например, как будет выглядеть иммутабельный `Square`, чтобы у него соблюдалось правило "длина = ширина"?

Comment: @andreycha: Попробовал дописать пример, надеюсь, так будет убедительнее для ТС.

Comment: Красиво. Можно еще все методы `Rectangle` сделать `final`, чтобы шаловливые оопшники не переопределили, как в примере в вопросе.

Comment: @zRrr: Хорошая идея, так и сделал.

Comment: Аплодисменты автору ответа очень  внятно и ясно.

Comment: @PeterSlusar: Спасибо!